# HTML5 Issue with backround-image and accompanied float image above it. Also cannot adjust opacity.

Tags: html, css, css-float, background-image

I am coding a website for my kids and it is also an assignment for a class. I am trying to put an image in the body as a background with having text on top of it. The image finally did show up however the floating box above it is mid page and will not float right to the edge of the page. I am including the .css file. The image file is in the same file as everything else and there is a link to the file.

```
h1 {
    color: green;
    text-align: center;  
}

h2 {
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
}

#header {
height:100px;
background:black; 
text-align: center;
text color: green;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    margin:0;
    dislay:block;
    color: #000000;
    background-image:url('trees.jpeg') &nbsp;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

#footer {
    height:50px;
    background:black;
    text color:green;
    text-align:left-side;
}

#content {
    height:1000px;
}

table {
        width:100%;
    Height:500px;
}
```

The link in the page looks like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dio.css">
</head>
```

My homepage is set up differently so I entered the information for the image straight into the page as it is not linked. This is the head.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #header {
            height:100px;
            background:green;
        }
    </style>

    <style>
        h1 {
            color:black;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <style>
        h2 {
            color: green;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <style>
        p {
            text color:blue;    
        }

    </style>

    <style>
        #sidebar {
            width:10%;
            height:1000px;
            float:left;
        }
    </style>

    <style>
        #content {
            float:left;
        }
    </style>

    <style>
        #advertising {
            width:10%;
            height:1000px;
            float:right;
        }
    </style>

    <style>
        #footer {
            height:50px;
            text-align:center;
            background:green;
            text color:black;
            clear: both;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            width:100%;
            height:1000px;
            margin:0;
            dislay:block;
            color: #000000;
            background-image:url('trees.jpeg') &nbsp;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

What am I doing wrong? I researched the issue an have been trying different things to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the background issue with the following HTML and CSS:

HTML header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dio.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="dio.js"></script>
  <script>
      window.alert("Welcome to our DIO site!")
  </script>
  <script>document.getElementById('someId').style.color = '#00FF00';</script>
  <style>
      body {
          height:1150px;
          width:1280px;
      }

      #advertising {
          background:olive;
          width:20%;
          height:1000px;
          float:right;
      }

      #sidebar {
          height:1000px;
      }

      #footer {
          height:50px;
          width:1280px;
          background:black;
          text-align:center;
          clear:both;
      }

      p {
          font-size: 22pt;
      }

      #content {
          text-align:center;
      }
  </style>
  </head>
```

and the CSS

```
h1 {
    color:#ADFF2F;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    color:#ADFF2F;
    text-align: lcenter;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p, strong, summary, section, h3, p2 {
    color:#ADFF2F;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a, h1, h2, p, strong, summary, section, h3, p2 {
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
} 

a:link {
    color:#FF69B4;
}

a:active {
    color:#e03a3e;
}

a:hover {
    color:#e03a3e;
}

header {
    height:100px;
    width:1280px;
    background:black; 
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

html {
    background:url('trees.jpg') #98FB98 no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}

body {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#content {
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:inline-block;
    width:60%;
    height:1000px;
}

#sidebar {
    background:olive;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
}

table {
    width:1020px;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:5px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    color:#00FF00; 
    font-weight: bold;

}

thead {
    background: #3056A0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table > caption {
    font-weight: bold;
}

tfoot {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-align:right;
    font-weight: bold;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #808000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

tbody tr {
    background: #808000
    font-weight: bold;
}

footer {
    height:50px;
    width:1280px;
    background:black;
    text-align:center;
    clear:both;
}

#salesDetails, #contactList {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    margin: 15px;
    padding:15px;
}

label {
    width:150px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

input {
    width:200px;
}

.formRow {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see an `&nbsp;` at the end of the `background-image` property. Try replacing it with the semicolon.

Also, for your homepage, you can combine the styles under one `<style>` tag.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate that. I put the &nbsp there as I saw it was a suggestion. I have been trying different things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. It seems like this is supposed to be an easy process but I'm getting nothing.

Comment: May be silly to ask, are you sure the file extension is "jpeg" and not "jpg"?

Comment: They are jpg extensions

Comment: Ensure the image has a .jpeg extension in its properties. The URL matters. See this jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/ar0tqf7t/

Comment: What has your browser inspector shown you when viewing the body style? It should show a pop-up of the image itself if it's being referenced correctly. I'm also assuming you're also retaining the other changes suggested. Other issues I see are the `text color` properties under the `p` and `#footer` styles. The correct property is just "color".

Comment: I made the changes you have suggested. I do not see a pop up of the image. I've even tried selecting a picture of png extension. I am still getting nothing.

Comment: I have gotten the background image to display by using the syntax as background: url(image.jpg). Now I am attempting to make it more transparent with opacity but in my first try the image stayed the same and the forefront items became more transparent. My page 1 that is not linked to css file won't load the image yet so I'm considering linking it to the css file.

Comment: I was able to get the opacity to work and the background image to work fine. However the box floating on the right side on page 1 keeps getting pushed downward by extra text entered into the #content area. I don't quite understand why this is happening as I am not trying to access or manipulate this particular box.